# JQuery accessing remote site with $.ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I broke this down to the absolute simplest code that will not work.  I made a simple Echo Test on my webservice that will take a string as a parameter and echo it back.  I wrote the javascript code that I've been working on in order to access this method here:

http://jsfiddle.net/stephenbayer/CaHqY/9/

I really need to know, why I am getting an error, and why the only message I'm getting back is the error string "Error" from javascript.  How do I fix this and get this working.

This is a web service that has been running using standard SOAP through WCF, and we had a client that requested access through javascript.  Sounded crazy to me, but I didn't think it would be that difficult.  I can not find any good clear information about getting these cross-domain calls to work at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do a Cross-Domain Call via normal AJAX due to the Same Origin Policy, you need to do a **[JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)**-Call for that.

Perhaps you could use [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) but you need to be careful because then youmight be vulnerable to cross site scripting.

Answer (score 1):

Modern browsers prevent cross-domain requests in order to protect users from XSS attacks.

To handle data coming from another domain, you need one of those 4 solutions :

- [modified headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control) on the xml server side
- [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) request and response
- a proxy so that your browser thinks that both domains are the same
- relaxed protection in the browser (not possible on all of them)

Note that the first 2 solutions involve to change the XML server.

Answer (score 1):

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery

good luck

Answer (score 1):

The others are right.
You have to use JSONP instead of JSON.

But there are an alternative:

Instead of using the ajax direct with the other domain, use it with your own domain, creating a new webservice in your server, using php for example.

Then, in your php ws you can call the external webservice and it will work. Use `file_get_contents()`.

I use it to get addresses codes using a public server:

```
$remote_data = @file_get_contents('http://republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?formato=json&cep='.urlencode($_REQUEST['cep']));

echo $remote_data;
```

Comment: The client that is trying to access the web service states that they have no PHP or any server side processing available to them.  That sounds odd to me, but they state that it has to be a pure javascript solution.  This service is in production and working for standard SOAP calls, I don't want to break functionality for the SOAP that others are using to handle a one off situation with a client using just javascript.  It has been a bane to try to help one client without breaking things for the rest.

Comment: Are they using java script to crate a mobile app, like phoneGap? This is very complicated then... Nowadays everyone developing such level should have at least a free small php/mysql test server for those situations.

Comment: @stephenbayer sounds like CORS might be the right thing for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is stopping the request because of [the same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  You can only make an xhr (i.e. ajax) to the domain from where the javascript was loaded.